# Missing timestamp when using TypeORM and postgresql

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

This is my user entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'email' })
  email: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at', nullable: true })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

When I select column from table user with code:

```
const query = User.createQueryBuilder('users');

query.select([
   'users.id',
   'users.email',
   'users.createdAt',
   'users.updatedAt',
]);
return query.find();
```

The result contains both create and update timestamp. But with code below, timestamp is disappear:

```
query.select([
   'users.id',
   'users.email',
   'users.created_at',
   'users.updated_at',
]);
return query.find();
```

And when I set logging true in typeORM options, I run 2 queries and both results have created and updated time. Thank for your attention.

Comment: users.createdAt and users.created_at is not the same. Why do you use different code?

Comment: @FrankHeikens when I log 2 query and execute them in dbeaver, I saw both have created and updated time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name option you pass to **@CreateDateColumn** and **@UpdateDateColumn** is just the way to change the name of the column in postgresql database for your preference, they can't be used to refer to their values.

If you not use the option name (**created_at** and **updated_at**) in two of those fields, by default the name of the column in database is the same as the name of property that you defined (here is **createdAt** and **updatedAt**).